# Does your institution has or have eye donation center? Or Has your institution eye donation centre?

Tags: questions

which one is correct sentence? 
Does your institution  *has or have*  eye donation cente? In this sentence, which one I should use either has or have?

Comment: When the auxiliary *do* appears, it is the only verb inflected for number and tense. The other verbs appear in the plain form. So it's "does have" and "did have."

Answer (score 0):

Either of these is fine:

```
Does your institution have an eye donation centre?
```

or

```
Has your institution got an eye donation centre?
```

Hope that helps,

Alan.